# Coroutine Exits while loop, although condition is still met

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a coroutine function written for Unity which is as below:

```
IEnumerator initialize_reference_att()
{
    Quaternion zero = new Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 0);
    while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero)
        Debug.Log("This line is required otherwise exits while without looping");
        yield return null;

    reference_attitude = Input.gyro.attitude;
    Debug.Log("Reference attitude set to " + reference_attitude);
    yield return null;
}
```

In this way it works as expected however when I write the while loop as below:

```
while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero)
    yield return null;
```

the execution of while loop ends although Input.gyro.attitude == zero condition is still true. Apparently it has something to do with returning from coroutine immediately after while loop without doing any other thing. Because when I add an debug log line(as in the first code snippet), it works as expected. Does anybody have any idea why it behaves in that way? My issue is solved but I only want to understand why it happens. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Your first snippet is a dead loop if the condition is true, and since Debug.Log can block the UI thread, your editor will stop responsing when it runs.

Comment: Consider using a simple time-based interpolation function instead of coroutines as the latter if used incorrectly is akin to `Application.DoEvents`.  Additionally it teaches bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job.

Answer (score 4):

This is basically the good old missing curly braces story:

```
while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero)
    Debug.Log("This line is required otherwise exits while without looping");
    yield return null;
```

basically equals writing

```
while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero)
    Debug.Log("This line is required otherwise exits while without looping");

yield return null;
```

=> without the `{ }` for enclosing a scope the `while` only applies to the **first** following expression after it

---

what you want is

```
while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero)
{
    Debug.Log("This line is required otherwise exits while without looping");
    yield return null;
}
```

---

> Because when I add an debug log line(as in the first code snippet), it works as expected.

Let me doubt that. Your first snippet is an endless loop that the way it is written should crash your entire app as soon as the condition is `true` once.

In contrary actually I would expect

```
while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero)
    yield return null;
```

which basically equals

```
while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero)
{
    yield return null;
}
```

or also simply

```
yield return new WaitWhile(() => Input.gyro.attitude == zero);
```

would allow to yield once a frame => continue in the next frame and check again. Except something happened we all waited for and Unity suddenly made the API multi-threading ready you would always get the same value for `Input.gyro.attitude` during the same frame

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Considering the fact that I have been writing Python code lately for most of the time I apparently forgot about curly braces like a newbie :) The reason why I don't use Quaternion.identity is because when the app runs Input.gyro.attitude reads (0, 0, 0, 0) for a short time. And since I want to save initial attitude of the phone I need to wait until gryo reading is not zero(I'm using phone attitude changes in the app). If I compare it with identity, it immediately considers reading is okay because identity is (0, 0, 0, 1) so it is not equal to (0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: My aim is to wait until reading is not (0, 0, 0, 0), that's why it is not an endless loop. Even without curly braces the code works but of course it keeps waiting until reading is not (0, 0, 0, 0) which is not my intention. I want the rest of the app to continue running until gyro reading is valid. But thanks anyway for your answer

Comment: @Patroclos without the braces I would expect your loop to be stuck forever at `while (Input.gyro.attitude == zero) { Debug.Log("This line is required otherwise exits while without looping"); }` .. since it is never `yield`ing in there nothing on the outside would update the `Input.gyro.attitude` value ... except Unity suddenly started to implement proper async API

Comment: Input.gyro.attitude is updated internally by mobile phone. It's the output of phones attitude. So it is updated outside the scope of my script. Otherwise you're right it would stuck forever

Comment: yes it is data fetched from your device ... however the Unity engine will only update it once a frame because it is single threaded

Comment: What I was asking originally was, with only while and yield codes (without debug line), it exits loop although condition was still true. I mean I try to wait until reading is not (0, 0, 0, 0) but eventually when coroutine ends, reference_attitude variable still stores (0, 0, 0, 0). In that case how come it exits while loop I dont understand.

Comment: I don't know about it's update frequency but it worked without curly braces. It worked with curly braces too which is more sensible. I just tried it :)